# GrandParent relationship of pom.xml in Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I need to create project like this.
Child - Product class
Parent - Store Product object in array
Grand parent - View Products

here,

> Grand parent -> parent -> child

inheritance is created.
I want to configure pom.xml as like this so when i build Grand parent, it automatically build all its child modules. how can i acheive this by parent-child relationship of pom.xml? Is maven support multi leval inheritance?

Comment: This might help https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module

Comment: Thanks, but i wants to know about grand-parent - child relationship in this article only parent-child relationship is given @R

Comment: building could be solved via modules if you have them in one repository. If you have them in multiple repositories i don't know how you would trigger a build. I think this would depend on your CI solution. I know for example that jenkins has a plugin that can look at maven dependencies and triggers builds but i never used it